# How are interfaces invoked?

Tags: java

I have an interface containing `void doThis();`. I've implemented the interface in my `Main` class and it automatically added `public void doThis() { ... }` to my class. If I'm in `Second` class, how do I invoke `doThis()` in `Main`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you implement an interface, you're making a class.  Interfaces are implemented by instance methods on that class.

To invoke an instance method on a class, instantiate the class, and invoke it as you would any other instance method:

```
Main m = new Main();
m.doThis();
```

Per my example code, you might want to pass an instance of `Main` into `Second` instead of creating the instance inside `Second`.  You can pass this in via the interface instead of via the concrete class type:

```
public class Second
{
    public void doSomething(SomeInterface si)
    {
        si.doThis();
        // other code here...
    }
}

// Some code outside those classes, that uses both classes...

Second s = new Second();
SomeInterface si = new Main();
s.doSomething(si);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void methodInSecond() {
    ThingInterface ti = new Main();
    ti.doThis();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, then

```
new Main().doThis()
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Main(").doThis();` will work. If you want the object to be **reused**, do like this

```
InterfaceName obj=new Main();
obj.doThis();
//other things you do with the obj object
```

Here the thing to remember is, even you can't create objects of interfaces, you can how ever use **interface references**.